# Wordpress Fatal error: Uncaught Error: syntax error

Tags: php, wordpress

I am facing error in the code line no 134

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: syntax error, unexpected end of file
in /taxonomy-product_category.php on line 134

The code working in some server can and some server looking above the error message can anyone please help me what's wrong in the code, how can I resolve the syntax error thanks in advance

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying Archive pages
 *
 * Used to display archive-type pages if nothing more specific matches a query.
 * For example, puts together date-based pages if no date.php file exists.
 *
 * If you'd like to further customize these archive views, you may create a
 * new template file for each specific one. For example, Twenty Fourteen
 * already has tag.php for Tag archives, category.php for Category archives,
 * and author.php for Author archives.
 *
 * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Fourteen
 * @since Twenty Fourteen 1.0
 */

get_header(); ?>

    <section id="primary" class="content-area">
        <div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">

            <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

            <header class="page-header"><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
                <h1 class="page-title">
                    <?php
                    if ( is_day() ) {
                        /* translators: %s: Date. */
                        printf( __( 'Daily Archives: %s', 'twentyfourteen' ), get_the_date() );
                    } elseif ( is_month() ) {
                        /* translators: %s: Date. */
                        printf( __( 'Monthly Archives: %s', 'twentyfourteen' ), get_the_date( _x( 'F Y', 'monthly archives date format', 'twentyfourteen' ) ) );
                    } elseif ( is_year() ) {
                        /* translators: %s: Date. */
                        printf( __( 'Yearly Archives: %s', 'twentyfourteen' ), get_the_date( _x( 'Y', 'yearly archives date format', 'twentyfourteen' ) ) );
                    } else {
                        _e( 'Archives', 'twentyfourteen' );
                    }
                    ?>
                </h1>
            </header><!-- .page-header -->
<section id="product-list" class="section">
            <div class="bandInner">
<?php
if ( function_exists('yoast_breadcrumb') ) {
yoast_breadcrumb('
<p id="breadcrumbs">','</p>
');
}

?>  <h1 class='pageTitle'><?php
    printf( __( ' %s', 'twentyten' ), '<span>' . single_cat_title( '', false ) . '</span>' );
?></h1>
<? 
wp_nav_menu( array( 
    'theme_location' => 'product-category',
    'container'      => 'ul',
    'menu_class'     => 'prodCats',
) );

?>
<style>
ul.prodCats li{
    display:initial!important;
}
ul.prodCats li.current-menu-item a {
    color: #8b2131!important;
}
</style>
<article id="mainContent">

                    <ul id="prodList">
    <?php
                // Start the Loop.
                while ( have_posts() ) :
                    the_post();

                    /*
                     * Include the post format-specific template for the content. If you want
                     * to use this in a child theme, then include a file called content-___.php
                     * (where ___ is the post format) and that will be used instead.
                     */
                    ?>  
                    <li>
                    <div class="prodCtn">
                                    <a class="prodImgCtn prodLink" href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>">
                                        <?php 
                                        $img = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_field('product_image'), "thumb_product" ); 
                                        ?>
                                        <img class="prodImg" src="<?php echo $img[0]; ?>"/>
                                    </a>
                                    <div class="prodCont">
                                        <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>" class="">
                                            <p class="prodHd"><?php the_title(); ?></p>
                                        </a>
                                        <p>
                                            <?php  
                                                $givchars = 350; 
                                                //$postgiv = the_field('product_description'); 
                                                $postgiv = get_field('product_description'); 
                                                $modgiv = substr($postgiv, 0, $givchars); 
                                                echo ' ' .$modgiv. '... ';
                                            ?>
                                        </p>
                                        <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>" class="btn">
                                            <span class="btnTxt">View More</span>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                </li>
<?

                    endwhile;?>
                    </ul>
                    <div id="show-hide-content" class="cat-content less-mode"><?php echo category_description(); ?></div>

                </article>

                    <?
                    // Previous/next page navigation.


                endif;
                ?></div><!-- #content -->
    </section>
        </div><!-- #content -->
    </section><!-- #primary -->

<?php
get_footer();
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some broken syntax in your code.  You have a few `<?`  when I believe you wanted `<?php`

I tried to clean it up for you so try this.

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying Archive pages
 *
 * Used to display archive-type pages if nothing more specific matches a query.
 * For example, puts together date-based pages if no date.php file exists.
 *
 * If you'd like to further customize these archive views, you may create a
 * new template file for each specific one. For example, Twenty Fourteen
 * already has tag.php for Tag archives, category.php for Category archives,
 * and author.php for Author archives.
 *
 * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Fourteen
 * @since Twenty Fourteen 1.0
 */

get_header(); ?>

    <section id="primary" class="content-area">
        <div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">

            <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

            <header class="page-header"><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
                <h1 class="page-title">
                    <?php
                    if ( is_day() ) {
                        /* translators: %s: Date. */
                        printf( __( 'Daily Archives: %s', 'twentyfourteen' ), get_the_date() );
                    } elseif ( is_month() ) {
                        /* translators: %s: Date. */
                        printf( __( 'Monthly Archives: %s', 'twentyfourteen' ), get_the_date( _x( 'F Y', 'monthly archives date format', 'twentyfourteen' ) ) );
                    } elseif ( is_year() ) {
                        /* translators: %s: Date. */
                        printf( __( 'Yearly Archives: %s', 'twentyfourteen' ), get_the_date( _x( 'Y', 'yearly archives date format', 'twentyfourteen' ) ) );
                    } else {
                        _e( 'Archives', 'twentyfourteen' );
                    }
                    ?>
                </h1>
            </header><!-- .page-header -->
<section id="product-list" class="section">
            <div class="bandInner">
<?php
if ( function_exists('yoast_breadcrumb') ) {
yoast_breadcrumb('
<p id="breadcrumbs">','</p>
');
}

?>  <h1 class='pageTitle'><?php
    printf( __( ' %s', 'twentyten' ), '<span>' . single_cat_title( '', false ) . '</span>' );
?></h1>
<?php 
wp_nav_menu( array( 
    'theme_location' => 'product-category',
    'container'      => 'ul',
    'menu_class'     => 'prodCats',
) );

?>
<style>
ul.prodCats li{
    display:initial!important;
}
ul.prodCats li.current-menu-item a {
    color: #8b2131!important;
}
</style>
<article id="mainContent">

                    <ul id="prodList">
    <?php
                // Start the Loop.
                while ( have_posts() ) :
                    the_post();

                    /*
                     * Include the post format-specific template for the content. If you want
                     * to use this in a child theme, then include a file called content-___.php
                     * (where ___ is the post format) and that will be used instead.
                     */
                    ?>  
                    <li>
                    <div class="prodCtn">
                                    <a class="prodImgCtn prodLink" href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>">
                                        <?php 
                                        $img = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_field('product_image'), "thumb_product" ); 
                                        ?>
                                        <img class="prodImg" src="<?php echo $img[0]; ?>"/>
                                    </a>
                                    <div class="prodCont">
                                        <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>" class="">
                                            <p class="prodHd"><?php the_title(); ?></p>
                                        </a>
                                        <p>
                                            <?php  
                                                $givchars = 350; 
                                                //$postgiv = the_field('product_description'); 
                                                $postgiv = get_field('product_description'); 
                                                $modgiv = substr($postgiv, 0, $givchars); 
                                                echo ' ' .$modgiv. '... ';
                                            ?>
                                        </p>
                                        <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>" class="btn">
                                            <span class="btnTxt">View More</span>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                </li>
<?php

                    endwhile;?>
                    </ul>
                    <div id="show-hide-content" class="cat-content less-mode"><?php echo category_description(); ?></div>

                </article>

                    <?php
                    // Previous/next page navigation.


                endif;
                ?></div><!-- #content -->
    </section>
        </div><!-- #content -->
    </section><!-- #primary -->

<?php
get_footer();
?>
```